# How do I gather info about contention rate?

Tags: .net, profiling, contention

I'm expecting that the load on the software I'm developing will increase over the next couple of months. Therefore I did some stress tests, and gathered some performance data with perfmon.
For one of the data I would like to have more information, and that's the contention rate.

So my question would be, if one of you knows, if it is possible to get more information about it than just this plain number. Afaik with WinDbg and SOS it's possible to drill deeper into this, but imho it's not very comfortable.
I would like to know if there is a tools available, which points the finger to bottlenecks..., or a tools that does not only create an overall counter, instead creates counters for classes or specific locks...

tia
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the CLR profiler I've used [AQTime](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/) to pinpoint bottlenecks in my projects. Its a very powerfull tool and is also well supported.

Comment: It won't provide you with data about a specific lock however it does give you enough data analyze contention for a resource (with a little work on you part ie setting up proper test runs and collecting the right data). AQTime on the other hand will tell you how much time you spent on a specific line of code which really helps you to find locks that are causing slowdowns